# Dúvida com backup postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Tenho na mesma máquina um servidor PostgreSQL 9.0 e também um PostgreSQL 9.4, tenho um banco de dados nesta última versão, quando tento fazer um backup tenho o seguinte erro, como poderia resolver este problema?

> C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.0/bin\pg_dump.exe --host localhost
>   --port 5432 --username "postgres" --format custom --blobs --encoding UTF8 --verbose --file "D:\bck_hospi.backup" "hospi" pg_dump: versão do
>   servidor: 9.4.1; versão do pg_dump: 9.0.19 pg_dump: interrompendo
>   porque a versão do servidor não corresponde pg_dump: *** interrompido
>   por causa de erro
>
> Process returned exit code 1.

Comment: a mensagem de erro indica que você está tentando fazer um backup do servidor com versão 9.4 a partir do `pg_dump.exe` versão 9.0, talvez usar o `pg_dump.exe` da versão 9.4 resolva o problema

Comment: Sim, isso eu já sabia! já encontrei uma solução para o problema! agradeço!

Comment: Conforme respondido nos comentários pelo **@sanção**: *"A mensagem de erro indica que você está tentando fazer um backup do servidor com **versão 9.4** a partir do **pg_dump.exe versão 9.0**, talvez usar o **pg_dump.exe da versão 9.4** resolva o problema."*

Comment: **Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! Vote consciente!** O seu voto é muito importante para nossa comunidade, contribua conosco e ajude a tornar a Stack Overflow em Português (SOpt) cada vez maior. Você pode saber mais em: [**Vote cedo, vote frequentemente**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente)

Comment: Da uma olhada nessa minha pergunta vê se te ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168698/como-realizar-backup-de-uma-base-de-dados-postgresql-atrav%c3%a9s-do-pgadmin-4