# Como realizar Backup de uma base de dados PostgreSQL através do pgAdmin 4

Tags: postgresql, backup

Estou tentando gerar um backup da minha base de dados PostgreSQL através do pgAdmin 4, porém sempre que tento realizar o backup um erro ocorre:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou configurando da seguinte forma as preferências do PostgreSQL:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quando configuro o backup estou fazendo desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se tiverem alguma sugestão de o que possa estar causando o erro.

Detalhes do erro que ocorre:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Editei a pergunta com as informações detalhadas do erro @Bacco

Comment: Ficou bem melhor. Quanto ao erro, precisava ver se fica salvo algum log que você possa acessar no servidor, a mensagem realmente não ajuda muito. Vamos ver se alguém com prática nessa ferramenta consegue dar alguma dica.

Comment: @Bacco obrigado pela ajuda de qualquer forma

Comment: O mais importante aqui foi sua boa vontade em melhorar o post. Isso facilita muito pra quem for ajudar (e consequentemente aumenta a chance de uma solução).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apesar de não ser exatamente a resposta que soluciona a minha pergunta, mas esse método de Backup do banco de dados funcionou para mim. De forma resumida, por meio do pgAdmin 4, por mais que eu tentasse o Backup sempre dava erro, então pesquisei e encontrei um solução que atendeu minha necessidade, via Prompt de comando, segue solução encontrada, caso alguém esteja precisando gerar um backup independente do método:

1º Passo: Ao abrir o Prompt de Comando (CMD) executar o seguinte comando:

**cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin**

Observação: Precisei estar nesse diretório para conseguir executar o comando `pg_dump.exe` necessário para realizar o Backup;

2º Passo: Logo após executar o seguinte comando:

**pg_dump.exe --host 127.0.0.1 --port 5432 --username postgres --format Custom --file C:\Backup\Backup_dados.backup BancoDados**

E pronto o backup do seu Data Base estará pronto em instantes. Ao final sua tela de comandos deve ficar assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]