# Erro em fazer Backup no PostgreSQL: Exit code 1

Tags: postgresql

Estou tentando fazer o backup de um bd no postgresql
- primeiro quando abro ele sempre faz um restoring automático que nunca acaba
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Tentando fazer o backup

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Me da essa resposta, e não faz o backup do banco
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso te ajuda em alguma coisa? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168698/como-realizar-backup-de-uma-base-de-dados-postgresql-atrav%c3%a9s-do-pgadmin-4

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Resolveu sim, era isso mesmo, vlw

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como realizar Backup de uma base de dados PostgreSQL através do pgAdmin 4](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/168698/como-realizar-backup-de-uma-base-de-dados-postgresql-atrav%c3%a9s-do-pgadmin-4)

Comment: Sinalizei como duplicada para não haver a necessidade de copiar a resposta aqui.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ok !